# Can anyone give me an example for PHP's CURLFile class?

Tags: php, curl, upload

I had a very simple PHP code to upload a file to a remote server; the way I was doing it (as has been suggested here in some other solutions) is to use cUrl to upload the file.

Here's my code:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.remotesite.com/upload.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('fileupload' => '@'.$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])); 
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

The server is running PHP 5.5.0 and it appears that @filename has been deprecated in PHP >= 5.5.0 as stated [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) under the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` description, and therefore, I'm getting this error:

```
Deprecated: curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead in ...
```

Interestingly, there is absolutely nothing about this Class on php.net aside from a basic class overview. No examples, no description of methods or properties. It's basically blank [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php). I understand that is a brand new class with little to no documentation and very little real-world use which is why practically nothing relevant is coming up in searches on Google or here on Stackoverflow on this class.

I'm wondering if there's anyone who has used this CURLFile class and can possibly help me or give me an example as to using it in place of @filename in my code.

Edit:

I wanted to add my "upload.php" code as well; this code would work with the traditional @filename method but is no longer working with the CURLFile class code:

```
$folder = "try/";
$path = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']). " has been uploaded";
}
```

***Final Edit***:

Wanted to add Final / Working code for others looking for similar working example of the scarcely-documented CURLFile class ...

**curl.php (local server)**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label> <input type="file" name="Filedata" id="Filedata" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $uploadDir = "/uploads/";
    $RealTitleID = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $ch = curl_init("http://www.remotesite.com/upload.php"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $args['file'] = new CurlFile($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],'file/exgpd',$RealTitleID);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);       
}
?>
```

**upload.php (remote server)**

```
$folder = "try/";
$path = $folder . $_FILES['file']['name']; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
}
```

Comment: Can you var_dump($_FILES)?

Comment: in upload.php? If I do that - how do I get it to return the result on my curl.php page? I was trying to do that earlier but nothing actually returns once I execute the submit code.

Comment: OK - Had to set the RETURNTRANSFER to true; so here's the result of var_dump($_FILES) under upload.php: `array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "phpC0F4.tmp" ["type"]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpj7C3Hv" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(483397) } } The file phpj7C3Hv has been uploaded`

Comment: Yeah - the $path you're trying to move the file to is not valid as it includes the directory separators in the tmp_name. You should either use just the 'name' or even better generate a new file name that is going to be unique e.g based on date or uniqid.

Comment: I'm at 99% WORKING - THANKS to you. The only thing missing is extension. There were a couple of things I needed to do - In curl.php I changed code to `$args['file'] = new CurlFile($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'],'file/exgpd',$RealTitleID)` to include mime type & postname. In upload.php I changed code to `$path = $folder . $_FILES['file']['name']`. at this point file is uploading to remote server; Only thing is it's not keeping the extension, just the file name. I just need to figure that part out.

Comment: "Only thing is it's not keeping the extension," Adding the 3rd parameter to CurlFile should resolve that. I'm still trying to get my php5.5 vm to boot to test though.

Comment: I do have the mime (2nd) and postname (3rd) parameters in curlfile() specified; and I've tried a few different things - but can't seem to get the file extension. It's uploading the file & keeping the original filename; but no extension!

Comment: GOT IT!! 100% Working. Had to use `$RealTitleID = $_FILES['Filedata']['name']`. Was using pathinfo with the wrong parameters. Everything is working perfect. Thank You.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is a snippet on the RFC for the code: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$args['file'] = new CurlFile('filename.png', 'image/png', 'filename.png');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
```

You can also use the seemingly pointless function `curl_file_create( string $filename [, string $mimetype [, string $postname ]] )` if you have a phobia of creating objects.

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$args['file'] = curl_file_create('filename.png', 'image/png', 'filename.png');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
```

Comment: Well - the bit I pasted is almost all of the useful bit that's not in the docs.

Comment: The page definitely gives a more useful look at real-world usage of the class; and adding $args['file'] = new CurlFile($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args); got rid of the Deprecated error; in fact it got rid of errors all together. The problem I have now is that my "upload.php" on the other end has become invalid. I'm not sure what changes I need to make to it in order to RECIEVE the file - because it's not actually receiving the file anymore.

Comment: You could add `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0') >= 0) ` to your code else fall back to `@`

Comment: one question...
when i try to catch my file, doesn't appear in $_FILE['file'] variable, is in $_POST['file'], you know why??

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your help, using your working code I was able to solve my problem with php 5.5 and Facebook SDK. I was getting this error from code in the sdk class.

I don't thinks this count as a response, but I'm sure there are people searching for this error like me related to facebook SDK and php 5.5

In case someone has the same problem, the solution for me was to change a little code from base_facebook.php to use the CurlFile Class instead of the @filename.

Since I'm calling the sdk from several places, I've just modified a few lines of the sdk:

In the method called "makeRequest" I made this change:

In this part of the code:

```
if ($this->getFileUploadSupport()){
    $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
} else {
    $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
}
```

Change the first part (with file upload enabled) to:

```
if ($this->getFileUploadSupport()){
  if(!empty($params['source'])){
     $nameArr = explode('/', $params['source']);
     $name    = $nameArr[count($nameArr)-1]; 
     $source  = str_replace('@', '', $params['source']);
     $size    = getimagesize($source); 
     $mime    = $size['mime'];
     $params['source'] = new CurlFile($source,$mime,$name);
  }

  if(!empty($params['image'])){
     $nameArr = explode('/', $params['image']);
     $name    = $nameArr[count($nameArr)-1]; 
     $image   = str_replace('@', '', $params['image']);
     $size    = getimagesize($image); 
     $mime    = $size['mime'];
     $params['image'] = new CurlFile($image,$mime,$name);
  }
  $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
} else {
    $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
}
```

Maybe this can be improved parsing every *$param* and looking for '@' in the value.. but I did it just for **source** and **image** because was what I needed.

Comment: Useful; thanks!  FWIW, I think it might make more sense to abandon the `@` format entirely and change your application code to use the `CurlFile()` approach.  But that's up for debate.  Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FOR curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please usethe CURLFile class instead

```
$img='image.jpg';

$data_array = array(
        'board' => $board_id,
        'note' => $note,
        'image' => new CurlFile($img)
    );

$curinit = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($curinit, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($curinit, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($curinit, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
     curl_setopt($curinit, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_array);
     curl_setopt($curinit, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
     $json = curl_exec($curinit);
     $phpObj = json_decode($json, TRUE);  
     return $phpObj;
```

Comment: When using the CurlFile technique, you shouldn't set CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD (it defaults to true, and it should be left that way), so that line should be removed.  CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD is no long even included in PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

CURLFile has been explained well above, but for simple one file transfers where you don't want to send a multipart message (not needed for one file, and some APIs don't support multipart), then the following works.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com');

$verbose = fopen('/tmp/curloutput.log', 'w+'); // Not for production, but useful for debugging curl issues.

$filetocurl = fopen(realpath($filename), 'r');

// Input the filetocurl via fopen, because CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS created multipart which some apis do not accept.

// Change the options as needed.

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-type: application/whatever_you_need_here',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $username . ":" . $password) // Use this if you need password login
    ),
    CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS => false,
    CURLOPT_UPLOAD => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3600,
    CURLOPT_INFILE => $filetocurl,
    CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize($filename),
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $verbose  // Remove this for production
);

if (curl_setopt_array($ch, $options) !== false) {
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    // A Curl option could not be set. Set exception here
}
```

Note the above code has some extra debug - remove them once it is working.

Answer (score 0):

**Php POST request send multiple files with curl function:**

```
<?php
    $file1 = realpath('ads/ads0.jpg');
    $file2 = realpath('ads/ads1.jpg');
    // Old method
    // Single file
    // $data = array('name' => 'Alexia', 'address' => 'Usa', 'age' => 21, 'file' => '@'.$file1);    
    // $data = array('name' => 'Alexia', 'address' => 'Usa', 'age' => 21, 'file[0]' => '@'.$file1, 'file[1]' => '@'.$file2);
    // CurlFile method   
    $f1 = new CurlFile($file1, mime_content_type($file1), basename($file1)); 
    $f2 = new CurlFile($file2, mime_content_type($file2), basename($file2)); 
    $data = array('name' => 'Alexia', 'address' => 'Usa', 'age' => 21, 'file[1]' => $f1, 'file[2]' => $f2);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://url.x/upload.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false); // !!!! required as of PHP 5.6.0 for files !!!
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // 1, 2
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $res2 = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $res2;
?>

<?php
    // upload.php
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    if(!empty($json)){ print_r($json); }
    if(!empty($_GET)){ print_r($_GET); }
    if(!empty($_POST)){ print_r($_POST); }
    if(!empty($_FILES)){ print_r($_FILES); }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a file to wordpress using the API you can do:

```php
$auth = 'YOUR-BASIC-AUTH-TOKEN';
$filePath = '/my/image/flower.png';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/media',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => file_get_contents($filePath),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="flower.png"',
        'Content-Type: image/png',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth,
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```