# Facebook PHP upload file from memory

Tags: php, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm reading an image from my S3 bucket in AWS and want to upload it to Facebook.

This is the reading function:

```
/**
 * Get a file from the s3 storage
 */
private function uploadPicture() {
    $picture = new FacebookPicture();
    $file = $this->s3Manager->getFile($this->subEndPoint,$this->verb);
    $picture->pictureContent = $file["Body"];
    $facebookAlbum = new FacebookAlbum();
    $facebookAlbum->album = new Album();
    $facebookAlbum->album->facebookAccessToken = "myAccessToken";
    $facebookAlbum->id = "myAlbumId";
    $facebookManager = new FacebookManager();
    $facebookManager->uploadPicture($facebookAlbum,$picture);
}
```

This is the uploading to Facebook function

```
/**
 * @param $facebookAlbum FacebookAlbum the album to upload the picture to
 * @param $picture FacebookPicture the picture to upload
 */
public function uploadPicture($facebookAlbum,$picture)
{
    $this->facebook->setAccessToken($facebookAlbum->album->facebookAccessToken);
    $this->facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $args = array();
    $args["message"] = $picture->description;
    $args["source"] = "@" . $picture->pictureContent;
    $data = $this->facebook->api('/'. $facebookAlbum->id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
    var_dump($data);
}
```

I keep getting :

```
curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead in <b>acebook-php-sdk-master/src/base_facebook.php</b> on line <b>1005</b><br />
```

I think that the problem is that the image content is saved in the memory.

How can I use the variable in my memory in order to post it to Facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

`@filename` has been deprecated in PHP >= 5.5.0 as stated [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) under the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS description , So thats the reason why you got the error .

you have your answer here at this [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032990/can-anyone-give-me-an-example-for-phps-curlfile-class), where different solutions are discussed . Also here is a snippet from [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload) for the code.

> **Currently, cURL file uploading is done as:**
>
> ```
>  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
>  $args['file'] = '@/path/to/file';
>  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
> ```
>
> This API is both invonvenient and insecure, it is impossible to send
>   data starting with '@' to the POST, and any user data that is being
>   re-sent via cURL need to be sanitized so that the data value does not
>   start with @. In general, in-bound signalling usually vulnerable to
>   all sorts of injections and better not done in this way.
>
> Instead of using the above method, **the following should be used to
>   upload files with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**:
>
> ```
>  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
>  $args['file'] = new
>  CurlFile('filename.png', 'image/png'); curl_setopt($curl_handle,
>  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
> ```