# PHP, Curl & Dotloop - Upload

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP and Curl and attempting to upload a document to Dotloop via their API. I am able to access Dotloop fine via the api to download docs, but uploading is confusing. Perhaps you can help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Per their API instructions, they state to do the following to upload a document via their api:

**Uploading A Document**

Upload a individual document (binary) via multipart form post

```
        POST /profile/:profile_id/loop/:loop_id/folder/:folder_id/document/
        content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=<BOUNDARY>
        content-length: XXX


        --<BOUNDARY>
        Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="disclosures.pdf"
        Content-Type: application/pdf

        <binary data>
        --<BOUNDARY>--
```

**Their example code:**

```
        $ curl -F 'file=@\"disclosures.pdf\";filename=\"disclosures.pdf\"" -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://api-gateway.dotloop.com/public/v2/profile/:profile_id/loop/:loop_id/folder/:folder_id/document/
```

**My PHP interpretation of their code...**

```
        $localFile = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/file.pdf";
        $token = '************';
        $fp = fopen($localFile, 'rb');
        $size = filesize($localFile);
        $boundary = hash('sha256', uniqid('', true));
        $headers = [
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
            'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary,
            'content-length: '.$size,
        ];
        $ch = curl_init('https://api-gateway.dotloop.com/public/v2/profile/*****/loop/*****/folder/*****/document/');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
            'file' => new \CURLFile($localFile, 'application/pdf','testFile123.pdf'),
        ]);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = json_decode(trim($result), TRUE);
        print_r($data);
```

**Update**

When I run my code it stalls for about 2 minutes and then it shows a 200 OK response but the file is not inside of my Dotloop account.

I know that I am accessing the file fine. When I echo the size of the file I get this:

```
 echo $size; // the size is 116625
```

Here is Dotloops API docs & the part of uploading a document: https://dotloop.github.io/public-api/#upload-a-document

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl request absolutely needs this if you're trying to upload binary data: [Can anyone give me an example for PHP's CURLFile class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032990/) At the moment all you're doing is sending them a string of a local file system path, which is of no use to them. You use either [curl_file_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-file-create.php()) or [new CURLFile()](http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php)

Change the following line

```
'file' => 'testFile123.pdf'
```

into

```
'file' => new CURLFile($localFile,'application/pdf','testFile123.pdf')
```

---

**Edit:** Remove `content-type` and `content-length headers`, the curl library should calculate those for you. Keep The `Authorization` header. This means you can remove the `fopen` stuff as `CURLFile` is all that is required.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Gawd I hate dotloop. So I changed to the code you've provided and now I get this response: Array ( [timestamp] => 1529618597716 [status] => 500 [error] => Internal Server Error [exception] => org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException [message] => Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly [path] => /public/v2/profile/*****/loop/*****/folder/*****/document/ )

Comment: Sorry I made an edit just now, the curlfile belongs with the `file` keyed data, also you probably don't need the `filename` key as that should be part of the `file` data.

Comment: Hm, yeah after the changes I still get the same error. Do you think this is a Dotloop issue?

Comment: Try ditching your `content-type` and `content-length` headers, the curl library should calculate those for you. Keep your `Authorization` obviously. This means you can ditch the `fopen` stuff as `CURLFile` is all you should need.

Comment: Neat, that's good to hear. Also, I have a feeling simply using `new CURLFile($localFile)` might be enough, as the extra parameters appear to be optional.